# Too many methods in class component in React – problem refactoring

Tags: reactjs

I am still fairly new to Reactjs and I am struggling with one thing.
I have built a small React app that consists of:

- App.js at the very top –the only class component that controls all the states
- 3 stateless components ( no1 , no2, no3 rendered in App.js (all with smaller components inside them, but that’s irrelevant)

App.js state includes 3 arrays all of which are used by those 3 stateless components rendered.

And then, in App.js I have around 400 lines of methods where I am modifying state by calling setState. That’s quite long....

My question is: is there anyway to split this file? To move  methods to their respective components: no 1, 2 and 3.

It seems impossible to me as having all the states in one class requires calling setState (having setState methods) in the same class only.

This might be a stupid question but:

Is it possible to modify state outside parent that holds this state (App.js), for instance, modify it in a stateless component no 1, and still keep parent updated about the change so that it can inform stateless components no 2 and no 3 about the change.

What’s the best practice in my case?

thanks

Comment: Since the code is workable, this is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Providing simplified component will also help. *Is it possible to modify state outside parent that holds this state* - this is what state management libs (Redux, Mobx) are for, can also be achieved with context API.

Comment: @SuavekN. Just wrote your an answer explaining how to achieve this. Let me know if your have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

What i do for code/logic splitting is:

- Keep the App.js as simple as possible
- If there is a lot of logic in a file/Component, i split the file to index.js and Component.js and keep the logic in index.js and the JSX/HTML in the Component.js

In your case you can:

1. Remove all logic from App.js
2. Create 3 folders no1, no2 and no3
3. Inside each folder create two files - index.js and ComponentNo1.js etc
4. In the index.js create a Component with state and in ComponentNo1.js create a stateless component that returns the JSX/HTML.

This is what I would recommend. If you find it hard to do it, post your App.js logic so that I could help you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure something like this is completely valid and is a common React practice.

I've written a sandbox to give you an idea of how this works:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zxl2owp2np

But to explain in detail, let's assume you have the following components:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 5
  };

  increaseValue = () => {
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value + 1
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Example1 value={this.state.value} increaseValue={this.increaseValue} />
        <Example2 value={this.state.value} />
        <Example3 value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Example1 = (props) => {
  const value = props.value;
  return (
    <div>
      I am Example1. The value is {value}
      <button onClick={() => props.increaseValue()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const Example2 = (props) => {
  const value = props.value;
  return (
    <div>
      I am Example2. The value is {value}
    </div>
  );
}

const Example3 = (props) => {
  const value = props.value;
  return (
    <div>
      I am Example3. The value is {value}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Our main App component has a state value of 5 that we pass into our 3 child components. The child components are all using that value to display data. In the App component, we defined a state-updating function called increaseValue, which we pass in to Example1 as property. Now Example1 can use increaseValue by calling `props.increaseValue()`

props.increaseValue() is bound to our App component's execution context. So it will update the value in App's component state. Now with the updated value, it gets shared across all our Example components for use.

Regarding your question about moving methods to the components that are using them. This is not a common practice. Typically you define the function inside the component where the state is going to be updated. Meaning, if you have a function that is meant to update the App component, it should be defined in the app component.